# How to run Neural Net on GPU without python frameworks?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I coded a deep learning model from scratch in python(using numPy) without using any frameworks like keras or tensorflow. So far my model works fine but it runs on CPU.

How should i modify my code so as to run it on GPU instead?

Comment: Did you write it with NumPy? If so, then you need to use some framework like CuPy with some code modifications to operate with GPU-backed tensors.

Comment: yes i wrote it with numpy. Could you link me to where i can learn how to do this?

Comment: I don't have anything in bookmarks, but I think you can find something yourself. Actually, I'd agree with Nicholas that the easiest way is to just learn PyTorch. Sooner or later you'll turn to one of the deep learning frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most deep learning frameworks have APIs that are significantly similar to NumPy. I recommend you [take a look at PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-tensor-tutorial-py) as it will let you refactor your code reasonably intuitively to make use of your GPU via Cuda. Speaking as someone who has coded a neural network in NumPy, I would highly recommend learning a popular deep learning framework. It will be easier than learning to make your NumPy code run on a GPU (which is in any case a less useful thing to be able to do than to use NN frameworks that already exist).